# What commands can't be used at the end of an object's method (per PGF's object-oriented programming module)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Subsection 93.10 *Implementation Notes* of chapter 93 *Object-Oriented Programming* of the TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a states (the emphasis is mine):

> When a method is called, before the method call some code is executed that sets a global counter storing the current object id to the object id of the object being called. After the method call some code is inserted that restores the global counter to its original value. This is done without scopes, so some tricky `\expandafter` magic is needed. Note that, because of this process, **you cannot use commands like `\pgfutil@ifnextchar` at the end of a method**.

How can the commands that are like `\pgfutil@ifnextchar` in that they cannot be used at the end of a method, be characterized? What commands besides `\pgfutil@ifnextchar` should be avoided?

Alternatively, is there some convention I can follow that will make this concern moot? For instance, if I end all methods with `\relax`, or if I enclose all method bodies inside a TeX group.

Comment: Having worked a bit with PGF's OO module, and with LaTeX3, I heartily recommend the latter.  Is there a reason for using this module?

Comment: @LoopSpace: As far as I know, it is the basis for TikZ's native data visualization module. Does LaTeX3 too have an object-oriented programming subsystem?

Comment: Given that an associative array is all that is needed to implement OO, LaTeX3's props are all that is needed.  It may take a little more initial work to define the structure, but IMHO it is worth it.  This is also coming from a TikZ perspective: one of my packages was originally implemented using PGF's OO but it got too tangled to maintain and my code was far, far cleaner when I switch to LaTeX3.  Interfacing between LaTeX3 and PGF is reasonably easy.

Comment: @LoopSpace: Could you please elaborate on what you found unsatisfactory in TikZ's OO module? It looks really cool to me, and since TikZ is, in general, very well-written, I'd expect this module to be so too.

Comment: @LoopSpace What approach do you use for the interfacing? (I'm wondering if I'm unnecessarily duplicating stuff because I don't know the cleanest strategy.)

Comment: @cfr I usually define wrapper functions in LaTeX3 that invoke the corresponding TikZ/PGF ones.  You could take a look at the [hobby](https://github.com/loopspace/hobby/blob/master/hobby.dtx) code, particularly at the `\hobbyinit` function.  Trace it through the code to see its definition and use, and how that passes PGF commands through to the LaTeX3 underneath.

Comment: @EvanAad It is well-written.  It's just that LaTeX3 is better written.  PGF's OO tries to fit in with ordinary TeX programming, and therefore suffers from the drawbacks of programming in ordinary TeX.  LaTeX3 is a whole different programming paradigm and has much more of a standard programming feel.  So when trying to do something that involves more programming than not, I now reach for LaTeX3 as a first resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands that should be avoided at the end of a method's body are those that look-ahead in the input stream, such as `\futurelet`, or, more generally, any commands that assume that the expanded method body will be followed by the text that follows the method-call. The reason is that pgf's Object-Oriented Programming module inserts some book-keeping code into the input stream following the method's body (as well as preceding the method's body).

In order to explain this in greater detail, let's compare how a method-call is expanded vs. how a regular macro is expanded.

Suppose the input stream looks like this:

```
\mac(arg)<rest of the input stream>
```

where `\mac` designates a regular macro:

```
\def\mac(#1){<replacement text with #1>}
```

The above will be expanded as follows:

```
<replacement text with #1 substituted by 'arg'><rest of the input stream>
```

in particular, the first token of the `<rest of the input stream>` immediately follows `\mac`'s replacement text.

However, if the input stream looks like this:

```
\obj.meth(arg)<rest of the input stream>
```

where `\obj` is an object handle of class `C`, and `meth` is the name of a method defined in `C`:

```
\pgfooclass{C}{... \method meth(#1){<method body>} ...}
```

then the above will be expanded as follows (see the macros `\pgfoo@caller` and `\pgfoo@caller@cont` in `<pgf install dir>/modules/pgfoomodule.code.tex`):

```
<oo bookkeeping>%
\pgfoothis@count<\obj's id>\relax% (*)
<method body with #1 substituted by 'arg'>%
\pgfoothis@count<\pgfoothis@count's value just before (*)>\relax%
<rest of the input stream>
```

where `\pgfoothis@count` is the object id counter that gets incremented each time an object is created, as described in the first bullet point in the manual's Implementation Notes section (93.10).

In particular, the first token of the `<rest of the input stream>` does not immediately follow `\obj.meth`'s body.

As can be seen, you should also make sure that when the method has finished executing, the control-sequences `\pgfoothis@count` and `\relax` are not redefined.